# Why are these Tasks completing faster on IIS Express than in a console app?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-express

I have a bunch of Tasks that runs significantly slower when running in a console app compared to when run as an ASP.NET application on IIS express.

IIS Express take around 6s to complete, the console app takes around 12s. Both run a release build.

Same version of .NET v4.7.1, CLR is 4.0.30319. Same hardware. Same code.

The code that each task performs is CPU work only, no IO. I have run the code with a profiler, and I see no excessive garbage collection differences nor any other branch individually standing out - only that the collective amount of work takes half the time to complete on ASP.NET/IIS Express.

If running the work non-parallelized, the discrepancy is also a lot smaller, though still existing.

Why do I measure performance differences between running the same code in a console app and a web application running on IIS Express - and how to get the same performance in my console app/xunit test as in IIS Express, so I can reliably measure performance in an easily automated manner, outside of IIS Express.

And here's some code to demonstrate, what I'm rambling about...

I know the benchmarking could be done more thoroughly, but it quite consistently shows the same results - also with a lot more iterations.

A few xunit tests, running with xunit 1.9.2. Same code running as a console app demonstrates the same results:

```
void Work()
{
    // The work code is essentially doing something like this, but I demonstrate the exact same
    // results if this method is just a Thread.Sleep(). 

    var list = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), i);
    }
}

[Fact]
public void AspNetVsXUnitTest_TPL()
{
    void Run()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 250)
            .Select(x => Task.Run(Work))
            .ToArray());
    }

    // warmup
    Run();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var runs = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
    {
        Run();
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Average over {runs} runs: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / runs} ms");

    // Average over 3 runs: 7391,3071 ms
}

[Fact]
public void AspNetVsXUnitTest_Parallel()
{
    void Run()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 250), x => Work());
    }

    // warmup
    Run();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var runs = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
    {
        Run();
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Average over {runs} runs: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / runs} ms"); 

    // Average over 3 runs: 7779,8868 ms
}
```

Then there's a ASP.NET WebApi controller actions:

```
void Work()
{
    var list = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), i);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("tpl")]
public void AspNetVsXUnitTest_TPL()
{
    void Run()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 250)
            .Select(x => Task.Run(Work))
            .ToArray());
    }

    // warmup
    Run();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var runs = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
    {
        Run();
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Debug.WriteLine($"Average over {runs} runs: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / runs} ms");

    // Average over 3 runs: 3950,57063333333 ms
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("parallel")]
public void AspNetVsXUnitTest_Parallel()
{
    void Run()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 250), x => Work());
    }

    // warmup
    Run();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var runs = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
    {
        Run();
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Debug.WriteLine($"Average over {runs} runs: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / runs} ms");

    // Average over 3 runs: 4135,25496666667 ms
}
```

Now, why is running this piece of code so much faster when running on IIS Express vs running as a console app or in a unit test runner?

Comment: Have you discovered the reason? I am experiencing a similar speed difference. My application is CPU- and memory-intensive. When built as a console application, a task executes in 41 seconds. When built as an ASP.NET application and run in IIS Express in Visual Studio, it executes in *23* seconds. When run in IIS, it executes in 41 seconds, the same as a console application. I am baffled.

Comment: @Alessandro unfortunately not and the problem persists. I would very much like to hear about anything you might find out about this.

Comment: Yesterday I found out about server GC vs. workstation GC. I added the "gcServer" setting to the app configuration file of the console application. Now the console application is as fast as the ASP.NET app.

Comment: @Alessandro Thanks for getting back to me! Unfortunately it must be a different issue then, as the problems persists for me even for the same GC configuration. I'm glad you found a solution to your issue though :)